# Restart Row number in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, window-functions

I am creating one Sp in T-SQL i want to restart row number every four row any one help me 
row_number with partion is not useful 
like

```
rownum   column 1  coumn2
1
2
3
4
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Please add least add your actual raw data as a starting point.

Answer (score 3):

Modulo the row_number analytic:

```
SELECT
  ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY somecolumn) - 1) % 4) + 1 as restarting_rownumber
FROM t
```

If you don't have a column you want to order by, use:

```
((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT null)) - 1) % 4) + 1
```

But be aware it will not produce a stable/predictable row numbering

Comment: Very well done. +1 from me!

Comment: ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT null)) - 1) % 4) + 1 nice this help for me grate

Comment: On SO, if an answer is the one you used you should accept the answer by clicking the grey check mark to turn it green. You can also upvote that answer and any other answer you found to be helpful. Only one answer can be accepted but multiple ones might be helpful and should be upvoted. Doing this lets people know your question was answered and which answer or answers worked for you and were helpful to you in solving the problem. People here look at questions with no answers and also questions with answers, but no accepted answer (because it could be that the existing answers weren;t helpful)

Answer (score 1):

Cauis' answer is exactly how I would do it. I'll build on his answer by introducing the NTally table. Code is below. In short, it does what NTILE does but way, way faster. It can also be used here.

Note that this:

```
DECLARE @rows BIGINT = 13, @restart BIGINT = 4;

SELECT  
  RN = f.RN, 
  restarting_rownumber = (f.RN-1)%@restart+1
FROM core.NTallyRangeAB(1,@rows,0) AS f;
```

**Returns:**

```
RN  restarting_rownumber
--- --------------------
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   1
6   2
7   3
8   4
9   1
10  2
11  3
12  4
13  1
```

**Against a table:**

```
DECLARE @sometable TABLE (SomeId BIGINT IDENTITY, SomeText VARCHAR(40));
INSERT  @sometable SELECT TOP (10) NEWID() FROM sys.all_columns;

DECLARE @rows BIGINT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @someTable), @restart BIGINT = 4;

SELECT 
  s.SomeId, SomeText, Restarting_Number = (f.RN-1)%@restart+1
FROM        @sometable                    AS s
CROSS APPLY core.NTallyRangeAB(1,@rows,0) AS f
WHERE s.SomeId = f.RN
```

**Returns:**

```
SomeId               SomeText                                 Restarting_Number
-------------------- ---------------------------------------- --------------------
1                    8E7FFE75-F0E6-4F2A-BE86-D4F9417BEE30     1
2                    A4B90ABF-B482-433E-B3F0-0DAA399C024E     2
3                    7259BBFB-AAB2-43B4-BCE8-3F21E38E4119     3
4                    D0BA2DC6-7463-456B-AD0F-5287964DC013     4
5                    438D849D-BE09-4559-9B5B-2DE85F003E79     1
6                    98E07D33-1EAF-479C-B2FC-6101F1B0D5E5     2
7                    0930628A-3E01-44BD-A039-CDA815DFC54F     3
8                    7B91419A-0232-4628-8EB6-464F25620377     4
9                    9581664E-381A-4BF4-913B-B2487844FA66     1
10                   5C02AB18-BD46-47E1-8150-14EA713FF612     2
```

**NTally Code:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('core.NTallyRangeAB') IS NOT NULL DROP FUNCTION core.NTallyRangeAB;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION core.NTallyRangeAB
(
  @tiles BIGINT,
  @rows  BIGINT,
  @desc  BIT
)
/*****************************************************************************************
[Purpose]:
 NTallyRangeAB is a faster, 100% readless alternative to the ANSI SQL:2003 compliant
 T-SQL NTILE ranking function which:

  "Distributes the rows in an ordered partition into a specified number of groups. The 
   groups are numbered, starting at one. For each row, NTILE returns the number of the 
   group to which the row belongs...

   ... If the number of rows in a partition is not divisible by integer_expression, this
   will cause groups of two sizes that differ by one member. Larger groups come before 
   smaller groups in the order specified by the OVER clause. For example: if have 53 rows
   and the number of groups is five, the first three groups will have 11 rows and the two
   remaining groups will each have 10. If the total number of rows is divisible by the 
   number of groups, the rows will be evenly distributed among the groups."

   SEE: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ntile-transact-sql

  The ASNI SQL:2003 NTILE function allows developers to divide a set "as evenly as 
  possible." NTallyRangeAB(@tiles,@rows,1) returns the same value as NTILE(@tiles) for
  a set with @rows*rows.  NTallyRangeAB (n) does this by returning an ordered set of 
  Row Numbers (n.RN) and two columns of "Tile Numbers" (n.Tile and n.TileOp). n.Tile will
  be the same value as NTILE(@tiles) OVER (ORDER BY n.RN). n.RN can be used to *join* to
  the table with the column(s) that need to be divided into "tiles". Note this query:

   DECLARE @tiles BIGINT = 3, @rows BIGINT = 8, @desc BIT = 0;
     SELECT n.RN, n.Tile, [NTILE(@tiles)] = NTILE(@tiles) OVER (ORDER BY n.RN)
   FROM   core.NTallyRangeAB(@tiles,@rows,@desc) AS n;

  In this example ^^ the tiles are divided up where lower tile groups numbers(n.TN) always
  have an equal or greater number of members than the higher tile group numbers. The above
  query returns 3X 1's, 3X 2's but only 2X 3's. 

    The third parameter (@desc) can be changed to 1 to reverse the distribution so that the
  higher group always have an equal or greater number of members. This query is identical
  to the one above except that @desc = 1:

   DECLARE @tiles BIGINT = 3, @rows BIGINT = 8, @desc BIT = 1;
   SELECT n.RN, n.Tile, [NTILE(@tiles)] = NTILE(@tiles) OVER (ORDER BY n.RN)
   FROM   core.NTallyRangeAB(@tiles,@rows,@desc) AS n;

  Notice ^^ how the query returns 3X 2's and 3X 3's but only 2X 1's.

[Author]:
 AJB

[Compatibility]:
 SQL Server 2005+

[Syntax]:
 --===== Autonomous
  SELECT r.RN, r.Tile 
  FROM   core.NTallyRangeAB(@tiles,@rows) AS r;

 --===== Against a table using APPLY
  WITH anchor(RN,SomeValue) AS
  (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.SomeValue), t.SomeValue
    FROM   SomeTable AS t
  )
  SELECT      t.SomeValue, Tile = nt.Tile
  FROM        anchor AS t
  CROSS APPLY core.NTallyRangeAB(@tiles, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM anchor)) AS nt
  WHERE       t.RN = nt.RN;

[Parameters]:
 @tiles = BIGINT; requested number of tile groups (same as the parameter passed to NTILE)
 @rows  = BIGINT; the number of rows to be "tiled" (have group number assigned to it)
 @desc  = BIT;    when @desc=0 the function distributes the tile groups so that lower tile
                  group numbers always have an equal or greater number of members than 
                  higher tile group numbers. When @desc=1 the opposite is true: higher 
                  group numbers will always have an equal or greater number of members

[Returns]:
 Inline Table Valued Function returns:
 RN     = BIGINT; a row number beginning with 1 and ending with @rows
 Tile   = BIGINT; a "tile number" or group number the same 
 TileOP = BIGINT; an "opposite tile number"

[Dependencies]:
 core.RangeAB

[Developer Notes]:
 1. When there isn't any partitioning involved, core.NTallyRangeAB (which uses 
    core.RangeAB) is ~10-15% slower than core.NTally which uses a persisted tally table.
    core.NTallyRangeAB, however, doesn't generate any reads or require Tally table.

 2. For best results a P.O.C. index should exists on the table that you are "tiling". For 
    more information about P.O.C. indexes see:
    http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2012/sql-server-2012-how-write-t-sql-window-functions-part-3

 3. NTallyRangeAB is deterministic; for more about deterministic and nondeterministic functions
    see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178091.aspx

[Examples]:
--===== 1. Demonstrating how the function mimics NTILE
 --; To better understand NTallyRangeAB, run the DML with different values assigned to @rows and
 --; @tiles. Note how the tile column and NTILE produces the same results.

 DECLARE @rows BIGINT = 8, @tiles BIGINT = 3, @desc BIT = 0;

 SELECT rn, tile, NTILE(@tiles) OVER (ORDER BY rn) as [NTILE]
 FROM core.NTallyRangeAB(@tiles,@rows,@desc);

--===== 2. Using NTallyRangeAB is a faster alternative to NTILE (with no PARTITION BY clause)
  --; Run the code below from --;START to --;END 
  --; Note how you get the same result but how, the more rows you add, the more efficient 
  --; the NTallyRangeAB solution is, with respect to reads, when compared to NTILE: 
  --; e.g. NTILE against 100K rows = 200K+ reads, 0 (ZERO) reads for NTallyRangeAB

  --;START
    --; Declare variables
    DECLARE @rows BIGINT = 8, @tiles BIGINT = 5;

    --; Setup sample data
    DECLARE @SomeTable TABLE (SomeValue int primary key);
    INSERT @SomeTable
    SELECT TOP(@rows) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))*5
    FROM sys.all_columns a, sys.all_columns b;

    --; How to divide @some table into 3 tile groups using NTILE
    SET STATISTICS IO ON;
    PRINT 'NTILE version:';
    SELECT SomeValue, NTILE(@tiles) OVER (ORDER BY SomeValue) AS TileGroup
    FROM @SomeTable;

    --; How to divide @SomeTable into 3 tile groups using NTallyRangeAB
    PRINT CHAR(10)+'NTallyRangeAB version:';
    WITH anchor AS
    (
     SELECT SomeValue, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SomeValue) AS rn
     FROM @SomeTable
    )
    SELECT SomeValue, nt.tile AS TileGroup
    FROM anchor a
    CROSS APPLY core.NTallyRangeAB(@tiles,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @SomeTable),0) AS nt
    WHERE a.RN = nt.RN;
    SET STATISTICS IO OFF;
  --;END

--===== 3. Using NTallyRangeAB an alternative to NTILE with a PARTITION BY clause

  --; 3.1. Create sample table with 10 rows and 3 partitions
  IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#SomeTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #SomeTable;
  CREATE TABLE #SomeTable
  (
    PartitionKey int NOT NULL, 
    SomeValue int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_SomeTable PRIMARY KEY(PartitionKey,SomeValue)
  );

  INSERT #SomeTable
  SELECT TOP (12) 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))/5+1,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))*5
  FROM sys.all_columns;

  --; 3.2. Using NTILE and PARTITION BY
  SELECT 
    s.PartitionKey, 
    s.SomeValue, 
    NTILE(3) OVER (PARTITION BY s.PartitionKey ORDER BY s.SomeValue) AS TileGroup
  FROM #SomeTable s;

  --; 3.3. Using the NTallyRangeAB function
  WITH 
  anchor AS  -- Use ROW_NUMBER for your partitioning and sorting
  (
    SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY v.PartitionKey ORDER BY v.SomeValue), 
            PartitionKey, SomeValue
    FROM   #SomeTable AS v
  ),
  parts AS -- collect the number of rows per partition
  (
    SELECT   a.PartitionKey, mxrn = MAX(a.RN) 
    FROM     anchor AS a
    GROUP BY a.PartitionKey
  )
  SELECT a.PartitionKey, a.SomeValue, nt.tile AS TileGroup
  FROM        parts                       AS p
  CROSS APPLY core.NTallyRangeAB(3,mxrn,0) AS nt
  CROSS APPLY anchor                      AS a
  WHERE       p.PartitionKey = a.PartitionKey
  AND         a.RN = nt.RN;

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Revision History]:
 Rev 00 - 20190114 - Initial Creation - AJB
*****************************************************************************************/
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS RETURN
SELECT      RN     = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.RN),
            Tile   = t.RN,
            TileOp = t.OP
FROM        core.rangeAB(1,@tiles,1,1)                                  AS t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(IIF(@desc=0,t.RN,t.OP)))                            AS d(D)
CROSS APPLY core.rangeAB(1,@rows/@tiles+IIF(d.D<=@rows%@tiles,1,0),1,1) AS x;
GO
```